# Dynamically changing validation rules with select input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

As the title says I'm trying to add dynamically validation rules with add method but they simply do not work. I might be calling my inputs and select wrong which I might be not aware of I've based the add bits of this code from similar topics on stack.

Here is the form that I'm using

```
echo '<form id="first_form" action="#" method="POST" style="border: 0; margin: 0;">';
                    echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$formid.'" name="formid">';
                    echo '<h1>Season, Patch version & amount of champions</h1>';
                    echo '<select id="season" name="season" onchange="checkseason();">';
                        echo '<option value="newseasons" name="newseasons" selected>Season 3+</option>';
                        echo '<option value="oldseasons" name="oldseasons">Season 1, 2</option>';
                    echo '</select>';
                    echo '<input id="patch" type="text" name="patch" placeholder="e.g. 4.20" required autofocus><br/>';
                    echo '<input placeholder="Number of Champions" value="1" type="number" name="champ_number" min="1" max="20" required><br/>';
                    echo '<input type="submit" value="next">';
                echo '</form>';
```

And here is my jquery/javascript code

```
function checkseason(){
            d = document.getElementById("season").value;

                    $('#first_form').validate({
                        rules: {
                            patch: {
                                required: true,
                                remote: {
                                    url: "../checkpatch.php",
                                    type: "post"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                        messages: {
                            patch: {
                                required: "Please enter patch version.",
                                remote: "Patch with this number already exists."
                                }
                            },

                    });


                $('select[name="season"]').on('change', function () {
                    if ($(this).val() == "newseasons") {
                        $('option[name="newseasons"]').rules('add', {
                            minlength: 4,
                             messages: {
                                minlength: "Please enter 3 numbers"
                            }
                        });
                    } else if ($(this).val() == "oldseasons") {
                        $('option[name="oldseasons"]').rules('add', {
                            minlength: 8,
                            messages: {
                                minlength: "Please enter 8 numbers"
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

        }
```

UPDATE: Code right now works fine messages and minlength changes but the form doesn't include restriction on initiation I have to switch between those 2 dropdown options to activate them.

```
function checkseason(){
            d = document.getElementById("season").value;

                    $('#first_form').validate({
                        rules: {
                            patch: {
                                required: true,
                                remote: {
                                    url: "../checkpatch.php",
                                    type: "post"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                        messages: {
                            patch: {
                                required: "Please enter patch version.",
                                remote: "Patch with this number already exists."
                                }
                            },

                    });


                $('select[name="season"]').on('change', function () {
                    if ($(this).val() == "newseasons") {
                        $('input[name="patch"]').rules('add', {
                            minlength: 4,
                            maxlength: 4,
                             messages: {
                                minlength: "Please enter 3 numbers"
                            }
                        });
                    } else if ($(this).val() == "oldseasons") {
                        $('input[name="patch"]').rules('add', {
                            minlength: 8,
                            maxlength: 9,
                            messages: {
                                minlength: "Please enter 8 numbers"
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
        }
$(document).ready(function(){


            checkseason();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('option[name="oldseasons"]').rules('add', ....
```

You **cannot** attach a rule to an `<option>` element.  *(AFAIK, `<option>` cannot contain a `name` attribute either.)*

Rules can only be attached to `<select>`, `<textarea>`, and `<input>` elements of various types.

As far as your code, perhaps a typo, but it does not make sense to change the rule of the `<select>` element whenever the `<select>` itself is changed.  The user could never satisfy this.  Perhaps you meant to attach the rule to something else.

I also noticed you have rules defined inline with HTML5 validation attributes.  While the jQuery Validation plugin can pick these up, you're also defining rules within the `.validate()` method.  You should be consistent so your code is easier to understand and maintain.  Either declare all validation rules inline or declare them all within `.validate()`, trying not to mix the two techniques together.

---

The `.validate()` method is used for ***initializing*** the plugin and would not go inside any function or handler except for DOM ready. You're using an inline `onchange` handler to call your function. This does not make any sense when you already have a jQuery `change` handler.

Just use a DOM ready handler...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#first_form').validate({  // initialize plugin
        ....
    });

    $('select[name="season"]').on('change', function () {  // your select change handler
        // your '.rules()' methods, etc.
    });

});
```

And **REMOVE** the inline `onchange` handler from your HTML markup.

```
<select id="season" name="season">
    ....
```

- I presume that when you make a selection you would want the rules for `patch` changed.  Then you would attach `.rules()` to `patch`; NOT the `select` and NOT the `form`.

> UPDATE .... but the form doesn't include restriction on initiation I have to switch between those 2 dropdown options to activate them

- You would need an ***initial*** `minlength` & `maxlenth` rule set for `patch` on page load (do this within `.validate()`). Otherwise, the default selection will have no relevant rules until the `select` is changed the first time.
- Since the error message is the same, you do not need to change it for each condition.
- Remove the `name` attributes from your `<option>` elements.  They are not used for anything.
- Remove the inline HTML5 validation attributes for `patch` as you're already declaring your rules using `.validate()` and `.rules()` methods.

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/yaw41bd3/**

Comment: I've tried something like that $('select[name="season"]').on('change', function () {
      if ($(this).val() == "newseasons") {
       $('#first_form').rules('add', {
        minlength: 4,
         messages: {
         minlength: "Please enter 3 numbers"
        }
       });
      } else if ($(this).val() == "oldseasons") {
       $('#first_form').rules('add', {
        minlength: 8,
        messages: {
         minlength: "Please enter 8 numbers"
        }
       });
      }
     }); 

and can't really get it to work

Comment: @Higeath, I tried explaining in your other question, the `.validate()` method is for initializing the plugin and would not go inside any function or handler except for DOM ready.  You're using an inline `onchange()` handler to call your function.  This does not make any sense when you already have a jQuery `onchange` handler.  That's precisely why nothing is happening.

Comment: @Higeath, regarding the code in your last comment.  Now why are you attaching `.rules()` to the form?  As per my answer above, the `.rules()` method can ***ONLY*** be attached to `<select>`, `<textarea>`, and `<input>` elements... NOT to `<form>` elements.

Comment: @Higeath, look at my updated answer and working live demo.  See second bullet point to answer your comment.

Comment: @Higeath, did you look at my edited answer and live demo?  The second bullet specifically answers your updated question.